# ASP.NET Change Site.Master anchor from Content Page programatically

Tags: asp.net

The Master page (Site.Master) of ASP.NET web forms application has navigation anchors.  One of the anchors is as follows:

```
<li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="~/Login.aspx">Login</a></li>
```

How can I change the text "Login" to "Logout" and the href to "~/Logout.aspx" from the code behind of the Login.aspx.cs?

Comment: Wonder why does that has to be done from code-behind of login page and not the master page? Did you look into using LoginStatus control or LoginView control?

Comment: @gbs  The authentication is done in the Login code behind; this is why I was going to change the anchor there.  I am not familiar with LoginStatus control. I will look it up.  Thank you.

Comment: @gbs  The LoginStatus seems to be doing the job that I was looking for. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

at the top of your client page

Then add

```
public HtmlAnchor AA1
    {
        get
        { return A1; }
        set
        { A1 = value; }
    }
```

to your master page code behind

Then you can change href of your anchor A1 in client page (Login.aspx.cs in your case) like

```
this.Master.AA1.HRef="~/Logout.aspx"
```

Comment: you have to add using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; in Site.master.cs page and TO change text to "Log Out" use this.Master.AA1.InnerText="Log Out"

Comment: Nanosoft, thank you for the suggestion and the code.